# How to hide fields for different graphql types which return the same type for GraphQL HotChocolate

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I created 2 different methods using GraphQL HotChocolate which return the same object type. I need to hide different fields for each method. However, it does not happen when I look at the schema definition. This is an example for code first approach:

```
public class Query
{
    private readonly CharacterRepository _repository;

    public Query(CharacterRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository
            ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(repository));
    }

    public Human GetHuman(string id)
    {
        return _repository.GetHuman(id);
    }

    public Human GetHumanClone(string id)
    {
        return _repository.GetHuman(id);
    }
}
```

The object Human is just a simple class with properties

```
public class Human
    : ICharacter
{
    
    public string Id { get; set; }

    
    public string Name { get; set; }

    
    public IReadOnlyList<string> Friends { get; set; }

    
    public IReadOnlyList<Episode> AppearsIn { get; set; }

    
    public string HomePlanet { get; set; }

    
    public double Height { get; } = 1.72d;
}
```

The graphql type defined for Human and HumanClone. The *HomePlanet* property should be ignored for HumanType and *Name* property should be ignored for HumanCloneType.

```
public class HumanType
    : ObjectType<Human>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Human> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Interface<CharacterType>();

        descriptor.Field(t => t.Id)
            .Type<NonNullType<IdType>>();

        descriptor.Ignore(f => f.HomePlanet);

        descriptor.Field(t => t.AppearsIn)
            .Type<ListType<EpisodeType>>();

        descriptor.Field<SharedResolvers>(r => r.GetCharacter(default, default))
            .UsePaging<CharacterType>()
            .Name("friends");

        descriptor.Field<SharedResolvers>(t => t.GetHeight(default, default))
            .Type<FloatType>()
            .Argument("unit", a => a.Type<EnumType<Unit>>())
            .Name("height");
    }
}

public class HumanCloneType
    : ObjectType<Human>
{
    protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Human> descriptor)
    {
        descriptor.Interface<CharacterType>();

        descriptor.Field(t => t.Id)
            .Type<NonNullType<IdType>>();

        descriptor.Ignore(f => f.Name);

        descriptor.Field(t => t.AppearsIn)
            .Type<ListType<EpisodeType>>();

        descriptor.Field<SharedResolvers>(r => r.GetCharacter(default, default))
            .UsePaging<CharacterType>()
            .Name("friends");

        descriptor.Field<SharedResolvers>(t => t.GetHeight(default, default))
            .Type<FloatType>()
            .Argument("unit", a => a.Type<EnumType<Unit>>())
            .Name("height");
    }
}
```

As both graphql types return the same object, these types can not be registered globally.

It seems it should be possible to return the same object type from different graphql queries according to https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/v11/defining-a-schema/object-types but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a common type, I recommend to create two different Payload objects like "GetHumanPayload" & "GetHumanClonePayload" inheriting the common property from the parent class and add the require fields in the respective payload classes to manage the same.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).